# Intermediate value property for measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be measurable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} f dx =1$ Show that for any $r\in(0,1)$, there is a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ such that $\int_Ef dx =r$.

I have tried the interval $(-R,R)$. If I can show that $R \mapsto \int_{-R}^R f dx$ is continuous and I can use the intermediate value theorem to show that there is a $R$ such that $\int_{-R}^R f dx=r$. If I consider $|\int f(\chi_{(-R_1,R_1)}-\chi_{(-R_2,R_2)}) dx|$, I do not know to show the continuous since I think that $\int_{-R}^R fdx$ may not be finite for some $R$ or $\int |f|dx$ may not be finite. Thank you so much!

Comment: HINT: Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If the integral in the question is the Lebesgue integral (so that $f$ is not just measurable but Lebesgue-integrable), then $\int {|f|}$ must also be finite (although it could be made arbitrarily large by choosing appropriate $f$), and so $\int_{-R}^R f$ also exists and is finite.  Lebesgue-integrability is always absolute inegrability.  (This contrasts with an improper integral or a Henstock–Kurzweil integral.)

Comment: I am wondering why $\int|f|$ is finite. If we look at $f=1$ for $x>0$ and $f=-1 $ for $x\leq 0$, we have $f$ is measurable and $int f =0$ but $int |f|=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

So $f\in L^{1}({\bf{R}})$, so the absolute continuity of integral implies that given that $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $\displaystyle\int_{F}|f(x)|dx<\epsilon$ for any measurable set $F$ with $|F|<\delta$.

Now Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem implies that $\displaystyle\int_{[-R,R]}f(x)dx\rightarrow 1$ since $\chi_{[-R,R]}|f|\leq|f|$.

And we have $\displaystyle\int_{[-R,R]}f(x)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $R\downarrow 0$, so such an $\alpha$ is guaranteed by Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Does $\int f dx =1 $ imply that $f \in L^1$?

Comment: Yes, true, because in Lebesgue integration, $\displaystyle\int f$ exists if and only if $\displaystyle\int|f|$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function $f_R$ for any $R>0$ so that
$$
f_R(x)
=
\begin{cases}
f(x), & |x|<R\\
0, & |x|\geq R.
\end{cases}
$$
Now $I(R):=\int_{-R}^{R}f=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_R$, so you can keep the limits of integration fixed.

To prove continuity, you need to show that $\lim_{i\to\infty}I(R_i)=I(R)$ if $\lim_{i\to\infty}R_i=R$.
You can interchange the limit and the integral due to the dominated convergence theorem.
The function $f_R$ is dominated by $|f|$, which is integrable.
The fact that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$ exists as a Lebesgue integral means (among other things) that the absolute value has a finite integral.

Comment: Does $\int f dx =1 $ imply that $f \in L^1$?

Comment: @mnmn1993 Yes. In Lebesgue integration the integral of a signed function is only defined when the absolute value is integrable.

Comment: I am wondering why $\int|f|$ is finite. If we look at $f=1$ for $x>0$ and$ f=−1 $for $x≤0$, we have$ f$ is measurable and$ \int f=0$ but$\int|f|=∞$

Comment: @mnmn1993 No, in that case $\int f$ does not exist. The Lebesgue integral over the real line is not defined as $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^Rf$. There are not "improper Lebesgue integrals"; they are all defined the same way. This is quite different from the picture with Riemann integration.

Comment: Thank a lot! So I think $\int |f|$ comes before $\int f$. Since  $\int |f|$ should be defined by $\int f_+ + f_-$ and thus $\int f_+$ and $ \int f_-$ are finite,we can get $\int f$ by $\int f=\int f_+- f_-$. Is it correct?

Comment: @mnmn1993 Correct. When the positive functions $f_+$ and $f_-$ are both integrable, we define $\int f=\int f_+-\int f_-$. It is convenient not to define $a-b$ when $a$ or $b$ is infinite, especially when both are.